# 500 Internal Server Error PHP FILE

Tags: php, cpanel

I'm trying to submit a form using ajax into php file. But when I try to access the php file hosted by cpanel it keep saying

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@website.com and
>   inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might
>   have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

I've tried many solution. Change permission to 777 and adding some handler in .htaccess `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm` but nothings happened.

Here's the error log inside cpanel. 
"httpd[139208]: [error] [client] File does not exist: /home/mywebsite/public_html/500.shtml". I am not the administrator of the account so I have limited access on the cpanel.

This is my php code, actually all php file got 505 internal server error.

```
require("PHPMailerAutoload.php");
$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body = "name: " . $_POST['name'] . "<br/>". "email: " . $_POST['email']
    . "<br/>" . "Contact number: " . $_POST['contactnumber']
    . "<br/>" . "I'd like to talk about: " . $_POST['idliketotalkabout']
    . "<br/>" . "Some more detail: " . $_POST['somemoredetail'];

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->Username   = "test@gmail.com";
$mail->Password   = "password";
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
$mail->SetFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email'],$_POST['name']);
$mail->Subject    = "contact"; //SUBJECT TITLE
//$mail->AltBody    = "Thanks for your Inquiry..";
$mail->MsgHTML($body);  
$mail->AddAddress("testadmin@gmail.com", "test admin"); 

if(!$mail->Send()) {  } else {  }
```

It works perfectly in my local machine..

Anyone can help me out of this?! Thanks!!!

Comment: Maybe it's an error in the code, can you share your php file ?

Comment: Share your code, it may have some functionality errors

Comment: Check your server erro log

Comment: Edit your question and post your code there instead of posting it as a answer.

Comment: Are you getting a 500error for all files on your server?

Comment: Just the php files only @Starkeen

Comment: You should report this error to server administrator. Without checking Apache error log,we can only predict. Only your server administrator can know the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the permission on 644 and see what does it give you.
If the file is empty, without any code, do you get also the error?

Comment: I set it to 644 but it says 404 error in the whole site

Comment: Ah, okay, it is a .htaccess problem if you got 404, could you show your .htaccess file ?

Comment: AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm

But I remove it because the error stays the same

Comment: The user that created the file does it have chown on it ?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if we upload file directly from cpanel not from cms, our file automatic add dot (.) before php file ot html file ex: `.<?php`or `.<!DOCTYPE html>`and it will return error 500.
Check again those file from cpanel and edit, delete dot (.) before php file.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the hosting platform removes the file extension from

> $.ajax({
> url: 'mail' // instead of mail.php
> })

I hope this helps solve your problem

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35799327)